# C# Executable Executing directory

Tags: c#

What is the best method of getting the path the C# executable is running from?

I need to use it for temp folders etc and currently I'm using:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```

But I then need to do a:

```
.Replace("file:\\", string.Empty)
```

as this gives me a URI type path (i.e. has file:\ at the start) which is unusable with some other parts of my code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not an accurate answer to your question, however I would suggest to have a look at:

```
Path.GetTempFileName()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx

Comment: I would say that this *is* the accurate answer. Temp files are supposed to go to the temp folder. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 43):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: This is the only reliable way to get the executable's path across any c# project (winforms, wpf, console, etc.) and certainly the best answer to the original question. But, in this case it does sound like an app-specific folder in ApplicationData should be used. I would refrain from using the temp directory unless it is truly temporary (i.e.: the files won't be used for more than a few seconds or during a specific process).. I clear out my temp folder regularly.

Comment: Why do you need "Path.GetDirectoryName()", the Location property seems to provide the full path already.

Comment: @MikeK Location includes the file name but only the directory is needed  (see the title of this question) ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Try with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`
This returns the folder of your currently working directory.

Comment: I was using this and it worked fine... until the working directory was set to a different path than the executable!

Comment: This works when building a single file console app where Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) fails

Answer (score 4):

For temp folders etc. you should NOT use the executing directory for security reasons...
MS has something built-in for this:

You can use `ApplicationData` (for roaming users) or `LocalApplicationData` (for non-roaming users) or `CommonApplicationData` (for non-user-related things) from `Environment.SpecialFolder` - anything (files+folders) you create within those folders is already setup with the needed permissions/rights for the user running you app - nobody else (except perhaps Administrator) can go there... to make it even more secure you could encrypt data you put there...

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For **self-contained single file applications** (available since .NET Core 3.0) you should use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`. The assembly location will be empty so you can't rely on it.

### Example

```cs
using System.Reflection;

Console.WriteLine($"AppContext.BaseDirectory: {AppContext.BaseDirectory}");
Console.WriteLine($"Assembly.Location: {Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output (Not published)**:

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory: C:\[..]\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\win-x64\
Assembly.Location: C:\[..]\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\win-x64
```

**Output (Published / Single File):**

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory: C:\[..]\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\win-x64\publish\
Assembly.Location:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Application.StartupPath
```

It should return the path without the executable filename.

Comment: `Application.StartupPath` is only available for WinForms (i.e.: by referencing the System.Windows.Forms assembly).. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yep, forgot to mention that, @wasatchwizard, +1 to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the assembly has been shadow copied then `Assembly.Location` will point to the shadow copy of the dll.

If you want to know the location of the build output directory use `Assembly.CodeBase`, i.e.:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath)
```

Useful if you want to access other resources from the directory of the assembly for example when running test suite.

Answer (score 1):

- .NET Core 3.0 introduced `IHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath`.
- .NET Core 2.1 introduced `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` (obsolete since Core 3.0).

Personally I find that these are what I generally need: the place where included content is located.

I can confirm that `IHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath` also returns the desired result when running as a unit test. (Tested with xUnit, but the test framework *should* not matter.)

Comment: Unfortunately, Docker containers seem to fail to get the correct value in this property at the time of writing. When using a web host (and possibly when using a generic host), we should be able to fix it with something like `new WebHostBuilder().UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` from `Main`. For Azure Functions using Docker containers, however, this is not available.

Comment: For Azure Functions, we could resort to the following ugliness: `Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath), "..")`. The combine with the `".."` is to navigate up one directory, out of the extra nested bin folder that Functions apps create. Obviously, needing different code for Functions is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

string executableLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string txtfile = Path.Combine(executableLocation, "example.txt");