# How can I get my C# .exe to automatically recognize the directory that it's running FROM?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Executable Executing directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025269/c-sharp-executable-executing-directory)

I used 2010 Visual C# Express to write a little windows form .exe.  How do I get the program to "know" what directory it's running from so that it can read/write from/to whichever directory the user has put my .exe in?  Basically, I want my little .exe to be "portable", where it doesn't matter which folder/directory it's in, and yet it can "know" where all its files are.

Comment: see [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in) should help you out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

[`Application.StartupPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There are different approaches, but this worked for me.

```
string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: Careful. In general this will work, but if this code happens to reside in a DLL that is *not* where your main .exe is (example, if this DLL were in the GAC), then you'll get the wrong result.