# how do i know where my exe is located in users computer in C#

Tags: c#, vsto, exe

i have created a small addin for excel, but for configuration purposes, i need to determine where the user has installed the add-in, the specific location of the exe.
 How can i do this in C#??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025269/c-sharp-executable-executing-directory

Answer (score 1):

[Application.ExecutablePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx) should do the trick.

Comment: i tried that and i tried this Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)  ..the latter seems to work for me...thanks anyways

Comment: In the case of an assembly that gets loaded in another process context it's more correct anyway.